# GMAIL API: new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I am using gmail api. I am getting the following warning:

> new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)

from this code:

```
message = GMAIL.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=m_id).execute() # fetch the message using API
```

Here is my full code (mostly taken from gmail API):

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

Lists the user's Gmail labels.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow, argparser
from oauth2client import tools

from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init

# use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
init()

# Setup the Gmail API

def get_credentials():
    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id='845-ehe.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        client_secret='curo',
        scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
        user_agent='people_cal2sms')

    if not creds or creds.invalid:

        flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Importing required libraries
from apiclient import discovery

# Creating a storage.JSON file with authentication details
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify' # we are using modify and not readonly, as we will be marking the messages Read
store = file.Storage('storage.json') 
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
GMAIL = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

user_id =  'me'
label_id_one = 'INBOX'

# Getting all the unread messages from Inbox
# labelIds can be changed accordingly
unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds=[label_id_one], q="label:clinic_sms after:2018/9/14").execute()

# We get a dictonary. Now reading values for the key 'messages'
mssg_list = unread_msgs.get('messages', [])

print ("Total unread messages in inbox: ", str(len(mssg_list)))

final_message_dict_list = [ ]

def retrieve_phone_2_gmail_message_dict():
    phone_2_gmail_message_dict = {}
    for mssg in mssg_list:
        message_dict = { }
        m_id = mssg['id'] # get id of individual message
        message = GMAIL.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=m_id).execute() # fetch the message using API
```

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. Your code does not contain a reference to `new_request`.

Comment: I hope you did not put your REAL token clearly in your code! Anyone could use it and hack your account...

Comment: @xiawi too late! reading emails now....

Comment: @xiawi no worry, I've changed it before posting

Comment: Daniel Roseman I dont understand what is full traceback and how to get it. the output is: "new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)"